# ORM Datamodel not finding MySQLConnector assembly Visual Studio / DevExpress

Tags: c#, visual-studio, devexpress, xpo

I created a VisualStudio 22, DevExpress 22.2.4 WinForms Application to do some simple Database viewing etc. The Database is on MariaDB 10.
I added Grids, set the DataSource to XPO which created a unitofWork and a Collection for the chosen Table. To actually display Data i had to enter the connection String again in the unitofWork, but i functioned.
Now (about a week later) after adding a new table to the DB for no discernable reason I can not update the model from database any more, showing the error:

```
System.TypeLoadException

None of the following assemblies found: 'MySqlConnector', 'MySql.Data'. At least one is required.
```

MySqlConnector is installed for the Project via Nuget.

The Database is on a VM which i reset.
I installed MySql.Data via Nuget, deinstalled MySqlConnector and MySql.Data, reinstalled them and tried different versions.
I de-/reinstalled VS, started a new Project where i try to use the same DB.
Here it works in so far as it shows the correct tables in the DB after i add the connector via nuget.
But after i use the collections for grids, it can not retrieve details, then it breaks again with the same message.
After installing separate MYSQLConnector for Net from Microsoft the error changes to a type error
"can not cast from DBNull".
I'm stumped because it worked before and reverting the changes since last working via git does nothing.
I'd be very grateful for any pointers or theories, I'm out of ideas.
I'll gladly provide additional info if required.